# Mocking in the Google AppEngine Runtime

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mockito

I'm trying to do something within the GAE runtime that needs to do "mocking":

```
  private Mongo createMongo() {
    Mongo mongo = Mockito.mock(Mongo.class);
    ...
  }
```

However, this obviously cause an error since "reflection" is a restricted class:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.<init>(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:24)
    at org.objenesis.strategy.StdInstantiatorStrategy.newInstantiatorOf(StdInstantiatorStrategy.java:65)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.getInstantiatorOf(ObjenesisBase.java:76)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:59)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:111)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:51)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:52)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:41)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1014)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:909)
```

- Is there any workaround for this? Is there a way to make "reflection"
  work with GAE runtime?
- Are there any "emulation" library for `sun.reflect` that makes it possible to do reflection?
- Perhaps, to define which classes possible to be reflected? Like `@Reflectable` or something
- Or there already exist a Mock framework that works in AppEngine?

Update:

I found a similar question way back 2010:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine-java/uIWRftGl-fA

However no answer until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Engine apps run in a sandbox which places limits on what they can do.  An overview of the sandbox can be found here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_The_sandbox

One of the sandbox limitations is a restriction on the jre-bundled classes that an application can access.  The full list of jre-bundled classes an application is allowed to access is listed here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist

Why is ReflectionFactory itself not on this list of accessible classes?  Well, if you read the javadocs for this class you will find the following statement: "The methods in this class are extremely unsafe and can cause subversion of both the language and the verifier."  And so, this class can be used to subvert the sandbox.

Comment: Good job answer the question. try to complete the answer by answering all the questions asked